# Public website to host a yellow-page like project

Tags: web-hosting, web-applications, open-source

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements)

I am working on a community project which is website served as a yellow page of shared artworks among students. At first, I planned to do the website myself (say, Drupal), but worried about the maintenance effort, bandwidth, security, scalability, etc. So I am looking for a public service (e.g. tumblr or wordpress.com) ...

The project:

- each student post the artwork (one preview image and one attachment) somewhere on the net
- then the student loggin in the yellow page website to:

  - write a title and description of the artwork
  - upload the preview image
  - write the link to the download artwork
- any students can download the artwork, the website records the download count
- any students can vote a 5-star rating, the website records the rating count and calculate the average
- any students can view artworks via the web, sort by newest, rating or download count

Is there an existing website which can provide such a service?

Answer (score 0):

If its art related you might have a look a deviantart.com, it would seem to be the most suitable home for your project although I don't know the details of the service they offer.